# Как добавить Join в sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

У меня есть таблица appFields у нее рекурсивная структура

| id | main_id | slug | name | createdAt | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | tag | Tags | 2023-11-30 00:23:50 | 2023-11-30 00:23:50 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | All inclusive | 2023-11-30 00:24:21 | 2023-11-30 00:24:21 |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | Airface included | 2023-11-30 00:24:51 | 2023-11-30 00:24:51 |
| 4 | 1 | NULL | No change fee | 2023-11-30 00:24:54 | 2023-11-30 00:24:54 |
| 5 | 1 | NULL | FullRefundable | 2023-11-30 00:24:56 | 2023-11-30 00:24:56 |
| 6 | NULL | amenity | Amenities | 2023-11-30 00:27:51 | 2023-11-30 00:27:52 |
| 7 | 6 | NULL | Gym | 2023-11-30 00:28:26 | 2023-11-30 00:28:26 |
| 8 | 6 | NULL | Cribs | 2023-11-30 00:28:44 | 2023-11-30 00:28:44 |
| 9 | NULL | meal_plan | Meal Plans Available | 2023-11-30 00:29:33 | 2023-11-30 00:29:33 |
| 10 | 9 |  | Breakfast included | 2023-11-30 00:30:14 | 2023-11-30 00:30:14 |
| 11 | 9 |  | Lunch included | 2023-11-30 00:30:43 | 2023-11-30 00:30:43 |
| 12 | 9 |  | Dinner included | 2023-11-30 00:30:45 | 2023-11-30 00:30:46 |

У меня есть запрос который генерируется с помощью [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)
Вот два запроса который мне генерирует фреймворк, ниже объясню почему 2

```
-- Запрос Первый
    SELECT `appPost`.`id`,
           `appPost`.`slug`,
           `appPost`.`title`,
           `appPost`.`postType`,
           `appPost`.`priceTotal`,
           `appPost`.`priceWas`,
           `appPost`.`dateStart`,
           `appPost`.`dateEnd`,
           `appPost`.`top`,
           `appPost`.`createdAt`,
           `appPost`.`updatedAt`,
           `appPostType`.`id`        AS `appPostType.id`,
           `appPostType`.`slug`      AS `appPostType.slug`,
           `appPostType`.`name`      AS `appPostType.name`,
           `appPostType`.`createdAt` AS `appPostType.createdAt`,
           `appPostType`.`updatedAt` AS `appPostType.updatedAt`,
           `appFields`.`id`          AS `appFields.id`,
           `appFields`.`main_id`     AS `appFields.main_id`,
           `appFields`.`slug`        AS `appFields.slug`,
           `appFields`.`name`        AS `appFields.name`,
           `appFields`.`createdAt`   AS `appFields.createdAt`,
           `appFields`.`updatedAt`   AS `appFields.updatedAt`
    FROM `appPosts` AS `appPost`
             LEFT OUTER JOIN `appPostTypes` AS `appPostType` ON appPost.postType
             LEFT OUTER JOIN (`connectionPostFields` AS `appFields->connectionPostField` INNER JOIN `appFields` AS `appFields`
                              ON `appFields`.`id` = `appFields->connectionPostField`.`appFieldId`)
                             ON `appPost`.`id` = `appFields->connectionPostField`.`appPostId`
    WHERE `appFields`.`id` IN ('2', '7', '4')
    GROUP BY `appPost`.`id`
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT appFields.id) = 3
    LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;

-- Запрос Второй
    SELECT `appPost`.`id`,
           `appPost`.`slug`,
           `appPost`.`title`,
           `appPost`.`postType`,
           `appPost`.`priceTotal`,
           `appPost`.`priceWas`,
           `appPost`.`dateStart`,
           `appPost`.`dateEnd`,
           `appPost`.`top`,
           `appPost`.`createdAt`,
           `appPost`.`updatedAt`,
           `appPostType`.`id`        AS `appPostType.id`,
           `appPostType`.`slug`      AS `appPostType.slug`,
           `appPostType`.`name`      AS `appPostType.name`,
           `appPostType`.`createdAt` AS `appPostType.createdAt`,
           `appPostType`.`updatedAt` AS `appPostType.updatedAt`,
           `appFields`.`id`          AS `appFields.id`,
           `appFields`.`main_id`     AS `appFields.main_id`,
           `appFields`.`slug`        AS `appFields.slug`,
           `appFields`.`name`        AS `appFields.name`,
           `appFields`.`createdAt`   AS `appFields.createdAt`,
           `appFields`.`updatedAt`   AS `appFields.updatedAt`
    FROM `appPosts` AS `appPost`
             LEFT OUTER JOIN `appPostTypes` AS `appPostType` ON appPost.postType
             LEFT OUTER JOIN (`connectionPostFields` AS `appFields->connectionPostField` INNER JOIN `appFields` AS `appFields`
                              ON `appFields`.`id` = `appFields->connectionPostField`.`appFieldId`)
                             ON `appPost`.`id` = `appFields->connectionPostField`.`appPostId`
    WHERE `appPost`.`id` IN (1);
```

Вот Файл моделей model.js

```
const { sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require('../config')

const appPost = sequelize.define('appPost', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    slug: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    postType: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    priceTotal: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: 0,
    },
    priceWas: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: 0,
    },
    dateStart: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    dateEnd: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    top: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
    }
})

const appPostType = sequelize.define('appPostType', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    slug: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
})

const appField = sequelize.define('appField', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    main_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: null,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    },
    slug: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        defaultValue: null,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
})

const connectionPostField = sequelize.define('connectionPostField')

// Определение связей между моделями
appPost.belongsTo(appPostType, { foreignKey: 'postType' })

appField.belongsTo(appField, {
    as: 'parent',
    foreignKey: 'main_id',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

appPost.belongsToMany(appField, { through: connectionPostField })
appField.belongsToMany(appPost, { through: connectionPostField })

// Определение ассоциаций
appPost.hasMany(connectionPostField, { foreignKey: 'appPostId' });
connectionPostField.belongsTo(appPost, { foreignKey: 'appPostId' });

connectionPostField.belongsTo(appField, { foreignKey: 'appFieldId' });
appField.hasMany(connectionPostField, { foreignKey: 'appFieldId' });

sequelize.sync()

module.exports = {
    sequelize,
    Op,
    appPost,
    appPostType,
    appField,
    connectionPostField
}
```

Вот файл исполняемый index.js

```
const {
    Op,
    appPost,
    appPostType,
    appField,
    connectionPostField
} = require('./model')
const { sequelize } = require('../config')

module.exports = {
    getPost: async function (param) {
        try {
            let getJoins = [
                {
                    model: appPostType,
                    required: false,
                    on: { id: sequelize.literal('appPost.postType') },
                },
                {
                    model: appField,
                    through: {
                        attributes: [] // Отключаем атрибуты связи
                    },
                    required: false,
                    on: { 
                        id: sequelize.literal('appFields.id') 
                    },
                },
            ]

            let subQuery = param.field ? await appPost.findAll({
                include: getJoins,
                where: {
                    '$appFields.id$': {
                        [Op.in]: param.field,
                    }
                },
                group: ['appPost.id'],
                having: sequelize.literal('COUNT(DISTINCT appFields.id) = '+param.field.length+' '+param.limit+' '+param.offset),
            }) : false

            let posts = await appPost.findAll({
                include: getJoins,
                where: subQuery ? {
                    id: { [Op.in]: subQuery.map(item => item.id) }
                } : undefined
            })

            return posts

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

И так два запроса потому как первый для фильтрации и определения id которые нужны, та-же работает limit и offset если это нужно, второй это уже для филдов которые есть у поста

Мой вопрос
Как добавить include (он же Join) для того чтобы можно было увидеть
slug id name парента (родительского филда)
Например есть филд All inclusive, у него есть Парент Tags
Мне нужно как-то приджоинить чтобы было видно парента, сделать запрос на SQL я могу, а вот на sequelize собрать этот запрос сложновато, возможно кто-то знает как это сделать, плиз отзовитесь, ато уже целый день работаю над этим и чат GPT не помогает!)
Спасибо!